# parse "deep" JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a multi-level JSON:

```
{
    "1":{
        "name":"PHP",
        "slug":"/tag/php",
        "type":"Tag"
    },
    "2":{
        "name":"JavaScript",
        "slug":"/tag/javascript",
        "type":"Tag"
    },
    "3":{
        "name":"X-Browser Shadow",
        "slug":"/post/x-browser-shadow",
        "type":"Post"
    }
}
```

I would like to know what is the best way to parse this JSON, pure JS or jQuery, i don't care which of them.

Thanks :)

Comment: Well in JS, that's already an object, so no parsing needed. Which is kind of the beauty of JSON (JavaScript Object Notation). Just set a variable equal to it and walaa!

Comment: What do you mean parse? Convert a string to that object or you mean to look through and actually use the object?

Comment: [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is either built into the browser or can be added with JSON2.

Comment: It doesn’t matter how deep it is. Parse it the usual way, i.e. `JSON.parse` or `jQuery.parseJSON`.

Comment: the *"best"* way would be to parse it the **only** way you can in the browser: *with javascript*. The code you use will depend on what you want to do with the data and how you are getting the data.

Comment: `JSON.parse( object_string );`

Comment: i might have explained myself wrong, how can i work with it like in foreach loop?

Comment: Like @Jasper said, the beauty of JSON is that it is a JavaScript object. So iterate over it like you would any other object: `var obj = JSON.parse( object_string );
for (x in obj) { ... }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to parse a valid json string.

Then use

```
var data = JSON.parse(stringfiedJSON);
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided that is a string, jquery's $.parseJSON will read it and parse it into an object, however deep it is.

Modern browsers also have a JSON object with two methods: parse (this case) and stringify (the reciprocal).